# Print Out ArrayList of objects into JTextFields

Tags: java, sql, swing

I am retrieving data from database to arraylist of object , and then from arraylist to JTextFields .
 but im facing a problem with printing it out from the arraylist . 
how can i print the arraylist into the JTextFields !

```
try {   
    Class.forName(DRIVER);
    cn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "", "");
    stmt = cn.createStatement();
    rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Userpref");


    while(rs.next()){
        int id = rs.getInt("ID");
        String fName = rs.getString("FirstName");
        String lName = rs.getString("SecondName");
        double gpa = rs.getDouble("GPA");

        Student s = new Student(fName, lName, id, gpa);
        students.add(s);

        // how i can print out the arraylist into the JTextFields line by line !
     }                
} catch(Exception e) {
       System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: `"how i can print out the arraylist into the JTextFields line by line !"` -- Why would you want to do that? If you have multiple rows of data, wouldn't you rather display it in a JTable so you can see all rows of data at once?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels , because i need to print it out sorted and understandable in JTextFields , that's all

Comment: And so if you have 200 students in the ArrayList, your single JTextField is going to display all this data in some understandable readable way? Sorry, but this seems very hackish to me. If your answer is to create 200 JTextFields, then you're going about it wrong. I strongly suggest that you create a JTable that uses a custom TableModel based on the AbstractTableModel and that displays each row of Student data in an organized, sorted, and easy to read way.

Comment: Totally agree with Hovercraft. A JTable will display the data in a readable way and provides built in sorting.

Comment: no i didn't mean i want to create 200 JTextFields , but i want to separate the data in each object into 4 JTextFields (print it) which its FirstName and SecondName and GPA and ID .

Comment: Well, then please clarify: which row out of the 200 are your four JTextFields going to display?

Comment: When i click on next Button its going to perform to get the first object and then print it out into the tf1 for FirstName,tf2 For SecondName,tf3 For ID,tf4 For GPA. and so on !

Comment: So the user has to click the button 200 times to see all the student information? That is not a very friendly user interface. Is that the way you do your searches for your favourite song on a MP3 player? Do you see one song at a time or a list of songs?

Comment: Then your question needs to be improved -- it has nothing to do with database programming and all to do with holding data in an ArrayList and changing data displayed on the press of a JButton, something that your code shows no attempt at. If I were you, I'd create a small program that tries to do just this, without all the database code, and then if it doesn't work, post a question with this code. But I agree with @camickr that the design isn't good.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels , i understand you very well . but i need to get the idea how can i separate the object each time into jtextfields...i need something like scanner to start reading and separating data in each line, but scanner doesn't work in this way !

Comment: No, you wouldn't need Scanner because it is used for translating text into data, and you already have your data, so there's no need to translate anything. All you need is an int index field that holds the value of the current row, and in your Next Row JButton's ActionListener, you simply increment the index, check that it's not equal to or greater than the size of the list, and then display the Student attributes for the new index's value. I think that you're over-complicating your problem, and should try to solve it again.

Answer (score 0):

Will do the trick:

```
textField1.setText(textField1.getText() + fName + "\n");
```

**But** the correct and less consuming will be, to save all your students formatted at a StringBuilder and then setting your `textField` text with that `StringBuilder` data.

Comment: this is tricky but it only print all the data in one line and in one JTextField , how about if i want to print the line into 4 JTextFields ? so i need to separate the data first and then print it ?

Comment: Since Java 7 we can use [`System.lineSeparator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator()) as a platform appropriate line separator string

Comment: You did not gave any details, how your `jTextFields` are organize Array, ArrayList ? Are names.. nothing..

Comment: Again this all smells hackish, like a classic [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @user3151146: no one is asking for you to post 500 lines of code, but we are asking for you to ask a clear question. Again, if the ArrayList has 200 row entries, which row are your JTextFields going to display. Better still would be for you to describe the overall effect you're trying to achieve, not how you're trying to use code to solve it, because likely there's a better way to solve this.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels okay , each raw that is an object should be displayed into 4 textfields which is Firstname,Secondname,Id,GPA. and when i click on next button it should perform then next object and so on ...

Comment: @user3151146: see comment to original question.